# Is there a simple way to get Django 1.2.* (latest stable) installed?

Tags: ppa, python

I want to start developing for it. I could `easy_install` or `pip install` but I'd prefer a proper repo.

Is there a PPA that's up to date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django 1.2 is included in Maverick Meerkat (still under development), but it appears that an unofficial backport of it exists in a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/python-django).

I haven't tested the package, but it appears to be a simple rebuild of what's in maverick.

An official backport to lucid has been requested & will hopefully happen sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

For most kinds of software packages, I agree with you that getting them from the repository is preferable. I would argue that it's different with python development related packages, though - you mostly want the latest (stable or development) version, dependency checks are figured out automatically for you. If I were you, I'd just go with using pip.